# item is not appearing in list in android

Tags: android, listview

I have an listview of SMSItem objects . When any new sms arrives , it is showed in the list . But after clicking the list , the item is disappearing . The item is not showed in the list .

My arrayadapter is as follows :

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSItem> {

    List<SMSItem> smsBody;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber;

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<SMSItem> smsBody, String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource, smsBody);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;
    }

    public SMSItem getStr(int position) {
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public void setRead(int position, String smsMessageId) {
        smsBody.get(position).status = true;
        SMSItem smsItem = smsBody.get(position);
        smsItem.status = true;
        //smsBody.set(position, smsItem);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read",true);
        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                values, "_id=" + smsMessageId, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    /*  Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String selection = "address = ? AND body = ? AND read = ?";
        String from = "03590000004";
        String body =smsItem.sms;
        String[] selectionArgs = {from, body, "0"};

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);

        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public SMSItem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textfrom;
        public TextView text_sms;
        public TextView text_time;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "The index is "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);
        SMSItem smsItem = smsBody.get(position);
        String smsTextToDisplay = smsItem.sms;
        if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
            smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

        holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);

        holder.text_time.setText(smsItem.time);
        if (smsItem.status == false) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.light_blue_overlay));
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);    
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Where is the problem ? How can I solve this ? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated .

My onclick code is :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        try {

             View v = smsListView.getChildAt(pos  - 
                      smsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
             v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            SMSItem smsMessageStr = (SMSItem) arrayAdapter.getItem(pos);
            if (smsMessageStr.status==false) {

                // String smsMessageId = ((SmsArrayAdapter)
                // arrayAdapter).getId(pos);
                ((SmsArrayAdapter) arrayAdapter).setRead(pos, smsMessageStr.ID); 
                Toast.makeText(this, "ID is " + smsMessageStr.ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            setBadge();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SmsActivity.this,
                    ShowIndividualSMS.class);
            intent.putExtra("SMS", smsMessageStr.sms);
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "exception is " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing on row click?

Comment: are you able to navigate to indivisual activity after selectinon

Comment: Probably `v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` causing issue. try to set it to other color like Black

Answer (score 0):

> But after clicking the list , the item is disappearing

The problem is with onItemClickListener(...) of `ListView` not with adapter.

Comment: I have updated my question . Can you tell me in where the error remains ?

Comment: Even after the activity is relaunched , the item is disappearing .

Comment: can we have a screenshot? v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); can be the cause.